# Obtaining "Invalid string length" while running ng build of a library

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, source-maps, ng-packagr

In Angular (see spec below), trying to generate a large library, thus running `ng build <project>`, we obtain

```
❌  Generating "fesm2015"

Invalid string length
```

Indeed, fesm2020 build succeeded.

The dist sourcemap for fesm2020 reached 32MB, while the fesm2015 sourcemap reached 33MB (.mjs.map file).

The entire source code is about 200 components distributed in 1 single library.

#### Reproduction

- Create 200+ components and include them in a single library module
- run `ng build <project>`

#### Error

`Invalid string length` after `Generating fesm2015`

#### Environment

```
_                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 14.2.6
Node: 18.15.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.6
... animations, cli, common, compiler, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli           14.3.0
@schematics/angular             14.2.6
ng-packagr                      14.0.1
rxjs                            6.5.4
typescript                      4.7.3
```

Is the any suggestion that we can adopt, even something to get a clearer view of what's happening (no verbose error is printed). We'd like to avoid splitting the code into different libraries even if it seems to be a problem of source code size/length.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @NJS yes, by upgrading to Angular 16 (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25998)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appeared to be upgrading to Angular 16+, while splitting large codes into different library entry points.

> This should no longer be a problem with version 16+.